# What negative effect will happen when multiple threads write to the same file?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-2.0, integration-testing

The following is pseudo code of an integration test that is failing:

[Test]

```
void TestLogger()
    // Init static logger
    Logger.Init(pathToFile);

    // Create five threads that will call LogMessages delegate
    for i = 1 to 5 
    {
       Thread aThread = new Thread(LogMessages)
       aThread.Start(i);
    }

    // let threads complete their work
    Thread.Sleep(30000);

    /// read from log file and count the lines
    int lineCount = GetLineCount();

    // 5 threads, each logs 5 times = 25 lines in the log
    Assert.Equal(25, lineCount);


static void LogMessages( object data )
  // each thread will log five messages
  for i = 1 to 5 
  Logger.LogMessage(i.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
  Thread.Sleep(50);
```

The number of lines seem to change each time the test is run.  Sometimes the number of lines is 23 and sometimes 25.

After I dug through the code a little bit, I noticed that the log file is getting accessed at the same time by multiple threads (verified by tick count being the same).  There is no lock around the access to this file, but at the same time I see no exceptions being thrown.  Can anyone explain why the log line count between runs is inconsistent?  Furthermore, is this a negative effect of writing to the same file by multiple threads at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Race conditions, as you have here, are notoriously unpredictable. You never know how many writes won't work properly - it might even work completeely fine, sometimes. And yes, this is a negative effect of writing to the same file from multiple threads without synchronization.

Comment: To add to the answer above, if thread 1 Gets A, and adds B to A. Then thread 2 comes in and gets A, adds C to it.  thread 1 Saves AB to file, but because thread 2 already read the file, when it rewrites the file the file will only contain AC instead of ABC.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to verify simultaneity with Environment.TickCount, you're going to have a bad time. It only has accuracy of about 15 milliseconds (IIRC), so if the values are the same from two threads then all you really know is that they were logging within ~15ms of each other.

If your Logger class puts a lock around its access to the log file, that should be sufficient. Just create a sync object via `private static readonly object sync = new object();` and then do `lock (sync) { ... open/read/write the file ... }`. Otherwise you'll be at the mercy of the thread safety of whatever type of Stream you're using (hint: in general they're not thread safe).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest way to handle these sorts of producer/consumer deadlocks and other race conditions is to invoke the lock() builtin:

```
lock(Logger){
 //use your logger here
}
```

This will hold the other threads at bay. You can also use the sync lock style as mentioned briefly above. There's a good example of all the options available (and pros and cons) on this guy's site:

http://www.gavindraper.co.uk/2012/02/05/thread-synchronizationlocking-in-net/

Good luck.

Comment: .. and has poor performance to go with the simplicity. A 10ms seek will inflict a 10ms block of all app threads attempting to log - the one that got in is waiting on disk IO, the others waiting on the lock.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, multiThreaded logging is performed by queueing log entries, (blocking producer-consumer queue), to one logger thread that writes to the disk.  This keeps the lock time down to the time taken to push a *log entry onto the queue: next-to-no contention. The queue absorbs any disk latency, network delays etc.

Using a simple lock inflicts any disk/network latency/delay upon all calling threads.